# What is the equivalent of DenyAllFilter in log4j2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j, log4j2

I am migrating an application from `log4j` to `log4j2`.

Below code snippet is `log4j` related and there is a filter `DenyAllFilter` added.

```
<appender name="TEST_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
  ...
  ...
  <filter class="com.test.it.ModeFilter">
      <param name="Mode" value="Test" />
      <param name="Deny" value="false" />
  </filter>
  <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
</appender>
```

Should `DenyAllFilter` be defined in `log4j2` as well ? If so, then What is the equivalent of `DenyAllFilter` in`log4j2` so that it can be added in `RollingFile` under `log4j2.xml` as mentioned below.

```
<RollingFile="TEST_FILE" other sttributes ...>
  ...
  ...
<ModeFilter name="ModeFilter" other attributes ... />
??? what is the equivalent of DenyAllFilter???
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/DenyAllFilter.html), DenyAllFilter can be used to switch from the default "accept all unless instructed otherwise" filtering behaviour to a "deny all unless instructed otherwise" behaviour.

There is no direct equivalent to this in Log4j 2. Since you will need to rewrite your custom ModeFilter as a [Log4j 2 plugin](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Filters) anyway, you may want to change the accept/reject conditions for this filter instead.

Comment: many thanks for the response .. Remko. My understanding is that in Log4j2, only filters defined under <RollingFile> in this case will be applied and other filters that are a part of application will not come into picture.

Comment: Hi Remko.. adding more.. ACCEPT accepts log event and DENY denies log event. If I have only one filter definition in an appender and if log event related to that appender is denied, then the log event will be denied logging and no other filters will be applied to this appender or log event. Is my understanding correct ? Then, to implement DENYALLFILTER in log4j2, if I add a new custom filter that simply denies the log event, then will this be treated as a DENYALLFILTER or will it be a part of composite filter and even valid log events will be denied because of composition. Please clarify.

Comment: If one filter accepts, the event is accepted and no other filters (nor the event log level) will be checked. If one filter denies, the event is dropped. If the filter returns NEUTRAL then other filters and finally the log level are checked. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html

Comment: many thanks .. Remko. I have added a custom deny filter as the last filter which denies the log event simply. So, this should work like DenyAllFilter.

Comment: With such a filter you should not see any log events in your log file.

Comment: It is a composite filter .. Remko. Filter 1 (Threshold filter defining the minimum and maximum level), Filter 2 (based on mode in the current thread), Filter 3 (Deny filter which simply denies). If filter 2 accepts the event, then filter 3 will not be considered. If result of filter 2 is NEUTRAL, then filter 3 will reject the event. Is this right ?

Comment: ...unless my answer wasn't as helpful as I thought. In that case please let me know...